# Multiple Listener Issue on Firestore Collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing an app that allows users with the roles of donor or recipient to access a collection of donations to retrieve data. Donor users only need to retrieve the donations that they have created, while recipient users need to retrieve the donations that they have received. To achieve this, I have created two listeners for the donations collection, each with a different query based on the user's role using the where() method.

However, I have encountered an issue where if the donor listener runs first, it retrieves data without any problems. But when the recipient listener runs after that, it is unable to retrieve any data or only retrieves data that the first listener has not yet read. The same issue occurs in the opposite scenario.

I attempted to resolve the issue by canceling all existing listeners before creating a new one, but unfortunately, the problem persists. While it is possible to read the entire donations collection to avoid this issue, it may become inefficient if the collection grows too large.
Help!!

```dart
cancelAllListener() async {
    await donationListener?.cancel();
    debugPrint("Donation listener cancelled");
    await receivedDonationListener?.cancel();
    debugPrint("Received donation listener cancelled");
}

void listenToUserDonation() async {
    await cancelAllListener();
    allDonations.clear();
    debugPrint(
        "Listen to donations of user ${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid}");
    donationListener = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('donations')
        .where('donor', isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((event) async {
      isLoading = true;
      notifyListeners();
      for (var element in event.docs) {
        Donation donation = Donation.fromJson(element.id, element.data());
        allDonations.add(donation);
      }
      donations =
          allDonations.where((element) => element.deleteAt == null).toList();
      deletedDonations =
          allDonations.where((element) => element.deleteAt != null).toList();
      isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    });
}

void listenToReceivedDonation() async {
    await cancelAllListener();
    receivedDonations.clear();
    var uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
    debugPrint("Listen to received donations of user $uid");
    receivedDonationListener = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("donations")
        .where(
          'recipients.$uid',
          isNull: false,
        )
        .snapshots()
        .listen((event) {
      isLoading = true;
      notifyListeners();
      for (var element in event.docs) {
        var data = element.data();
        Donation donation = Donation.fromJson(element.id, data);
        receivedDonations.add(donation);
      }
      debugPrint("Received donations: $receivedDonations");
      isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }
```

Comment: Show us the code that does that.

Comment: @AlexMamo I don't think my code is relevant but I just updated it if you want. I use event.docChanges at first but after encounter the issue I changed to event.docs to see if it work but nothing change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I know what the issue is. It's my fault. I checked for the user's role before creating those listeners. However, after the user logs out, I immediately check for their role and create the listener. The problem is that the role hasn't been updated yet, so it gets stuck at the last user role and causes the issue.